# How can we hide the "publish all" button from the work-box?

Tags: publishing, workflow

Does Sitecore have out of the box option to hide the `publish all` button from the workbox?

The reason I want to do is, there are a few incidents of clicking `publish all` by mistake.

I want to keep the other three buttons:

1. Publish (selected)
2. Reject (selected)
3. Reject (all).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can't *only* hide the `Publish (All)` button. You would have to hide both the `Publish (Selected)` and `Publish (All)` buttons.

The `Publish (Selected/All)` button, is an action available when the item is in your `Approved` workflow state. The workbox screen will give you those 2 options (Selected/All) for each action you can take on the items.

To change that, you would have to customize the workbox, which as you have mentioned, is not a simple solution. I'd say, training would be easier than customization :)

Answer (score 1):

**Since I'm unable to find this option in Sitecore, I have been trying to customize it as described below:**

- To hide the `Publish (all)` programmatically, we need to change
  the behavior of the `private DisplayState() method` of the
  `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm` class from the
  `Sitecore.Client.dll` assembly.
- In the method, there is a loop to add commands and it's (all)
  counterpart. After customizing that class, we can configure workbox
  to use it by going to the
  `\Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Workbox\Workbox.xml` file and
  changing the following `<CodeBeside
  Type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm,Sitecore.Client"/>`

Comment: Is this an answer or an extension to the question?

Comment: If you want to do such customisation on workbox, then this is the way to do it as you have done. for example here you can see another customisation to display only latest version on workbox http://sitecorelabs.blogspot.com/2014/12/sitecore-custom-workbox-to-show-latest.html

Comment: This is an answer